# Need help with nfc on phone

Tags: nfc

I’m looking for a quick and easy way to extend the range on my Samsung s4 I’m currently using a iPhone 5 but I use a my old Samsung s4 for my music and I have these nfc connect speakers and was wondering if there is a simple way to in crease the range and speed of the nfc on my s4 so it is faster and easier to connect to my speakers. I’m not to much of a tech guy so I’m not look for something to complex maybe just a simple trick someone might know.

Comment: [What topics are OK to ask about and what are not](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

NFC only works over a **very short** distance, like 10 cm.

So the NFC is only used to **set-up** the connection, the music stream doesn't actually use NFC. That is either done via Bluetooth or WiFi. NFC is **completely unsuitable** for streaming music.

The Samsung Galaxy S4 is an old phone and might not support everything that is needed to do what you want. So your issues might have **nothing** to do with the range but everything to do with the S4 being too old.

Even if it was the range (which is unlikely) that was the problem, there is **nothing** you can do about that anyway.